# Can users edit all of the javascript on my website?

Tags: javascript, python, webserver

I want to get a users location based off their IP address. So I will get the browser to prompt the user for their location using the geolocation api and send that information to my backend.

Is it possible for users to edit the javascript that sends the geolocation to my server before the request happens? If so, what is a good way to circumvent this and get true location?

I am planning on not allowing those coming from Tor or a VPN, so that's not of concern to me. Just trying to make sure that users won't edit the javascript to be in a different area.

I saw I could use something like ipinfo.io with my Python server, but I'm not sure if this is as accurate as prompting the user for their location via the browser. (I'm trying to get their exact location, like a ride share app or any maps app has it).

Comment: Someone will likely still be able to forge an API request to your server. The only thing you can really do is server-side validation (e.g. make sure the location is valid).

Comment: To cut the long story short: the location provided by the JavaScript API can not be trusted (as any user input).

Comment: Point taken.. so is there a way to get accurate geolocation from an IP address or a request information via Python?

Comment: `an IP address` no ... `a request information` - what is that

Comment: sorry, should have elaborated the request information bit. Given a user making a get request to one of my endpoints with Python Flask, is there anyway to get latitude and longitude or precise location? I'm assuming no

Comment: What would you expect to get for a user on Mars?  This question is intrinsically nonsensical if you phrase it as an absolute (“true”, “precise”).  Even an ISP doesn’t necessarily know much: consider satellite Internet access, so it’s impossible to reliably do better than politely *asking* the user (and checking, imperfectly and approximately, via IP address).

Comment: I like the idea of checking and then just confirming that their IP address says it's the city where they claim.